# Check that a link has been clicked

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-docs, google-sheets-api, google-docs-api

I would like to keep track of how many times a certain link in Google Spreadsheets has been clicked. I have been searching but I can't seem to be able to find how to check whether a link has been clicked or if it is possible to attach onclick event on a link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

its not possible, you cant detect cell or link clicks.

Two possibilities here:

**One way** is to have a server (or an apps script service) be the link "proxy" and redirect to the final site as in:

script.google.com/.../exec?url=myurl.com

your script tallies the hit and then redirects the user. redirecting without an extra click might not be possible with apps script htmlService but its possible on your own server.

you can make the urls look pretty by using =hyperlink in the cells so users dont see the long url (until click)

**Another way** if you have control of the links you are pointing to is to use analytics on those pages. You can use the referer to tally views that came from a spreadsheet click, or you can explicitly add parameters to each url so that youcan later filter those comming from your sheet.

Answer (score 3):

A quick solution is to use the [Google URL shorten service](https://goo.gl/) for the links. This page gives you the number of clicks per link.